# MonoDevelop vs Xamarin vs SharpDevelop

Tags: .net, forms, web, cross-platform

As last couple of versions MonoDevelop download links is Xamarin this not a question for for versus? I am more wondering about the license for the Xamarin Windows, Linux (web and form) and also Mobile development. As there is no Xamarin download links for Linux (the ones in the site are not working), does it mean they are not planing to support Linux at all.

Also just saw there is another IDE called SharpDevelop, what is this exactly as far as I can tell it is only supporting Windows.

If you can give more information about cross platform IDE alternatives that would be great e.g. [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_(IDE)) but it does not support any web application development directly.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop is supported on Linux. You can get the 4.* packages from the official site here http://monodevelop.com/Download

If you want the latest 5.* packages, you get the packages and installation instructions here http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt. Or else you could build them yourself from their repository.